# Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\printserver\printername

Tags: powershell

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\printserver\printername
```

With `printserver` and `printername` replaced with my companies actual server and printer name, I get the error:

> Add-Printer: The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid. Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.

Seems pretty straight-forward, I cannot use `\` under the parameter `ConnectionName`. But this code was taken directly from [Microsofts own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/add-printer?view=win10-ps), so to me it's very weird that it doesn't work.

Have I missed something trivial or is there some bigger step I don't know about?

Comment: Are there spaces in the actual name?

Comment: Just quoting the MS documentation as your code isn't great for us as we can't see the code that generated the error. Using your actual code and just substituting any identifiable names is best. This leaves the code and variable formatting in place which is much more useful for us to diagnose you _actual_ issue.

Comment: If there are spaces in the printer name, try wrapping the printer name in quotes `Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\printsvr\Sales Shared Printer"`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method which I've used against Windows 8.1 Enterprise and Windows 10 Enterprise domain workstations.

To add a printer:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Scriptblock {RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\\PrintServer\ShareName }
```

To remove a printer:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Scriptblock {RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /gd /n\\PrintServer\ShareName }
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui